# How to randomly put number, strings in excel using pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 3000 rows of data in excel

```
id,product,store,revenue,data,state
1,Ball,,222,nil,,
1,Pen,,234,nil,nil,,
2,Books,,543,nil,,
2,Ink,,123,nil,,
```

- I need to fill the 3rd `store` column with random number between `1 & 5`

My code is giving every time 1, `df['store'] = df['store'].fillna(random.randint(1,5))`

- I need to fill the 5th `state` column with random string `{'CA', 'WD','CH', 'AL'}`

I need to create a 6th which is `country` column if 'CA', 'CH' in 5th column map to USA and 'WD', 'AL' map to Japan
`{'CA':'USA', 'CH':'USA', 'AL':'Japan'}`

Comment: check witt numpy random ..

Comment: @YOBEN_S i have added the details

Comment: I have provide the solution , let me if it work ~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try

```
n=len(df)
num=np.random.randint(1,6,size=n)
l={'CA', 'WD','CH', 'AL'}
state=np.random.choice(list(l), n)

df['store'] = df['store'].fillna(pd.Series(num,index=df.index))
df['state'] = df['state'].fillna(pd.Series(state,index=df.index))
df['country']=df.state.map({'CA':'USA', 'CH':'USA', 'AL':'Japan'})
```

Comment: what is the use of index=df.index?

Comment: @Nons make sure you have the same index for fillna , since pandas will always check the index , if the index match then it will fillna , other than that index not match , the original value will not change